# SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() doesn't compile?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a RGB Surface from another surface with SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom because it's a TTF surface and I want to change the depth to access the surface pixels, this function is supposed to return a SDL_Surface* pointer but the compilers says it returns an int and I cant assign the return to my SDL_Surface* pointer, which is weird because SDL_CreateRGBSurface works perfectly the way it's supposed to.

Here's the code and the compiler message:

```
SDL_Surface     *tmp = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(mySurface->pixels, mySurface->w, mySurface->h, 32, 32 * mySurface->w, RMASK, GMASK, BMASK, AMASK);

Compiling src/main.c: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'SDL_Surface *' (aka 'struct SDL_Surface *') from 'int' [-,-Wint-conversion]
  ...= SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(mySurface->pixels, mySurface->w, mySurface->h, 32, 32 * mySurface->w, RMASK, GMASK, BMASK, AMASK)
     ^
```

Minimal Reproductible program:

```
# include <SDL.h>
# include <SDL_ttf.h>
# if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
#  define RMASK 0xff000000
#  define GMASK 0x00ff0000
#  define BMASK 0x0000ff00
#  define AMASK 0x000000ff
# else
#  define RMASK 0x000000ff
#  define GMASK 0x0000ff00
#  define BMASK 0x00ff0000
#  define AMASK 0xff000000
# endif

int             main(void)
{
    SDL_Surface     *textSurface;
    SDL_Surface     *newSurface;
    TTF_Font        *font;
    SDL_Color       white = {255, 255, 255, 255};

    font = TTF_OpenFont()
    if (SDL_Init() || TTF_Init()
    || !(font = TTF_OpenFont("assets/fonts/SweetCreamy.ttf", 30))
    || !(textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "Test", white))
    || !(newSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(textSurface->pixels, textSurface->w, textSurface->h, 32, 32 * textSurface->w, RMASK, GMASK, BMASK, AMASK)))
        return (-1);
    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(newSurface);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Also turn up your compiler warnings if it didn't tell you about undeclared functions.

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler?  Are you sure you aren't `#include`ing SDL1's `SDL.h`?

Comment: I downloaded only sdl2 so it can't be SDL1

Comment: I'm using a makefile for compilation and until this function all worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom is being implicitly defined and as such is returning an int as is the default. Ensure you are including SDL.h.

Comment: I'm including SDL.h, and the classic SDL_CreateRGBSurface works but I dont know why SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom doesn't

Comment: Strange as SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom definitely does return an SDL_Surface... Also I don't really understand your goal here what exactly is your goal with the TTF surface

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. It's a good comment though.

Comment: The problem statement is broader than what this answer addresses. Also this answer makes assumptive statements about what OP has, or has not done.  (Which really does make it a better comment than answer.)

Comment: I want to access the pixels of my surface, but when you don't initialize a surface with SDL_CreateRGBSurface you can't choose the depth of pixels in byte so I can't edit my surfaces since my screen surface has a depth of 32 and my TTF surface has another depth so we can't access pixels the same as we access pixels in a 32 depth surface, so that's why i'm trying to convert it (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: @Fayeure In that case, just use SDL_ConvertSurface

Comment: @TTG Thanks, I didn't know this function existed, it works aswell.